# jQuery val() method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to read the value entered in the text box in one of my HTML form, for this I tried jQuery `val()` method, but it is not working, any idea why?

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="payment-form">
   <p>
      <label class="card-number" for="txt_cardno"><span>Card Number:</span></label>
      <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" class="card-number" id="txt_cardno" name="cardno" />
   </p>
   <p class="submit submit-button"><a class="btn" href="#">Charge Card</a><br><a class="btn" href="#" onClick="return false">Go Back</a></p>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submit").live("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var card_num = $('.card-number').val();
        alert(card_num);
    });
});
```

the jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/74neK/1/

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you're using jQuery 1.7.1 (in your linked JS Fiddle), in which case [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated. Use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: thanks @DavidThomas will use on()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the id to access it (faster):

```
 var card_num = $('#txt_cardno').val();
```

Comment: Yes great answer, the problem is usually that you have label name and class name the same. So # overrides this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You've given both the `<label>` and the `<input>` the `"card-number"` class.

Specify the `input` in the selector. Otherwise `.val()` gives you the value of the first element found (the `label`).

```
var card_num = $('input.card-number').val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74neK/3/

---

If you're really concerned with micro-optimization, you should use native methods:

```
var card_num = (document.getElementById('txt_cardno')||{}).value;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74neK/5/

Comment: but why do i need to add that extra input. ?

Comment: @user993563: I just updated my answer with more info. When jQuery finds more than one element, `.val()` will try to give you the value of only the first element found. In this case the `label` is first, so you don't get any value *(because labels don't have a value)*.

Comment: thnaks for the explanation, helpful indeed!!

Answer (score 3):

Your `<label>`'s `class` is the same as your `<input>`'s, so jQuery is trying and failing to retrieve the value of your `<label>`. Instead, refer to your `<input>` by `name` or `id`:

```
$('#txt_cardno').val()
```

I would recommend ID regardless, because jQuery optimizes it to `document.getElementById`, which is much faster.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the ID to access the element:

```
var card_num = $('#txt_cardno').val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74neK/4/ <- Example

Answer (score 2):

Select the `id` of your input element, as opposed to the `class`: http://jsfiddle.net/btgxu/